# Django Queryset get value

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to get the formatted datetime from the database, e.g. 2020-07-28 (stored this way in the DB).

If I pass the below to the template:

```
hello1 = Orders.objects.all()[:1].values('created')
```

it returns

```
<QuerySet [{'created': datetime.date(2020, 7,
28)}]>
```

I just need it to return the value in the view (not the template). Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple. We access the variable and reference the item number (in this case 0 as we are only getting the first value.

```
hello1[0]
```